# What (or what kind of element) is in $S ∩ I_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, direct-sum

> Let $R$ be a ring and let $R = I_1 ⊕ I_2$ be an internal direct sum. If $S$ is a subring of $R$ containing $I_1$ then $S = I_1 ⊕ (S ∩ I_2)$.

I am supposed to prove the that  $S = I_1 ⊕ (S ∩ I_2)$ with the condition given above, however, to start with, I do not know what (what kind of elements)  are in  $S ∩ I_2$.

Here is what I know:

$I_1 ∩ I_2 = 0$ (by the definition of internal direct sum). But now the fact that $S = I_1 ⊕ (S ∩ I_2)$ means that $S ∩ I_2$ is not empty? So what is in $S ∩ I_2$?

Comment: Of course $S\cap I_2\neq\emptyset$ since $0\in S$ and $0\in I_2$

Comment: You should proceed like this: for all $x\in R$, $x=x_1+x_2$ where $x_j\in I_j$ and are unique such whose sum is $x$ . Now if $y$ is in $S$, $y=y_1+y_2$. Then $y_2=y-y_1\in S$ since $I_1\subset S$. But $y_2$ is also in $I_2$. Thus $y_2\in S\cap I_2$, i.e., $y\in I_1\oplus (S\cap I_2)$. Can you do the converse for your own?

Comment: Why does $y \in S$ imply $y=y_1+y_2$? The structure of element in a ring can differ from the structure of elements in the subring. We know that $R = I_1 ⊕ I_2$ but not that $S = I_1 ⊕ I_2$ so why is  $y=y_1+y_2$?

Comment: Because every element in $R$ has that form